# trouble in using git commit -m

Tags: git

When running `git commit -m "Commit message"` It returns the error message:

> fatal: empty ident name (for ((null))) not allowed

and then asks for the account's default identity.

See the [command prompt screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyoPC.png)  for more details.

Comment: Have you read the text in the screenshot?

Comment: Please consider minimizing external links - the text from the console could be included in an in-line block.

Comment: You can highlight inline code by putting it between backticks (`), or create a code block by indenting text four spaces. [More details here.](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Related: [Git empty ident name (for <>) not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832926/git-empty-ident-name-for-not-allowed). Note that TortoiseGit users only see the "empty ident name" message, without any of the "tell me who you are" helpful text that comes from the command line. If you are seeing this when you are applying a patch, check out the question I linked in this comment.

Answer (score 22):

Just as the text in the screenshot says, you need to tell git who are you committing the code as, by using e.g.:

```
git config --global user.name "John Smith"
git config --global user.email "John.Smith@example.com"
```

Comment: for the first time in every client and every windows need to run this command (to init git for first commit ) if local git or if you want to conect to remote git

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your user name and email address, which sets your identity before you can commit anything. Please follow the instructions [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup#Your-Identity).

Answer (score 0):

You might not be setting the user details correctly:

**Incorrect:**

```
git config --global john.name "John Smith"
git config --global john.email "John.Smith@example.com"
```

**Correct way:**

```
git config --global user.name "John Smith"
git config --global user.email "John.Smith@example.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. After I set the configuration for the local repository by running

```
git config user.name "<INSERT NAME HERE>"
git config user.email "<INSERT EMAIL HERE>"
```

the error went away, thankfully.